# Eclipse not showing project files with git provider

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, github

I created a git folder on my disk and did `git init`, `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email`

I forked a repository on github and cloned it on STS by going through the following menu options in Eclipse:

File -> Import -> Projects from git -> Clone URI --> entered destination as the git folder

Then after the project (say name is `project1`) is copied into my git folder

I imported the project into my work space through the following steps

File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing maven projects -> Entered the root directory as the path to `project1` in the git folder

After the import I do a maven clean and build. I don't have any errors but in the project explorer on the projects I just see the M symbol which corresponds to a maven project.

But I can't see the small cylindrical yellow symbol which corresponds to the git symbol. When does this git symbol appear on the projects in STS? Did i miss some step?

Answer (score 3):

If you right-click on the project(s) you are missing, you can do 'Team -> Share' and select the git provider. It will automatically hook them up to the git team provider and you'll see the symbols appear.

If you're checking out a Maven project with git, you might find it easier to just do 'File -> Import -> Maven -> Import from SCM' and paste in the maven SCM for your project, which will be 'scm:git:https://github.com/...' - that will do the clone and set up the projects for you in one step.